# Picasso setting placeholder image but not the actual image

Tags: android, android-imageview, picasso

I am using the Picasso library on android to display profile images, but the image does not load for some reason and the app only displays the placeholder image.

```
Picasso.get()
            .load(R.drawable.ic_person_black_100dp)
            .placeholder(R.drawable.common_full_open_on_phone)
            .into(profileImageView);
```

Comment: Why do you need a placeholder if you are fetching from local resource?

Comment: @makata Initially I wrote the code without the placeholder but the image didn't load, so I tried adding the placeholder and I realized that the app is loading the placeholder but not the image

Comment: Is `ic_person_black_100dp` a vector drawable?

Comment: @makata Yes, it is

Comment: Vector drawable is not supported. Follow [this](https://github.com/square/picasso/issues/1109) thread for more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Picasso 2.X doesn't support vector drawable. You can either use Glide or use a workaround:

```
Glide.with(context)
   .load(R.drawable.my_vector_drawable)
   .into(mImageView);
```

When load() call fails, the error handling mechanism of Picasso seems to work with vector drawables:

```
Picasso.get()
    .load(R.drawable.my_vector_drawable)
    .error(R.drawable.my_vector_drawable)
    .into(mImageView);
```